# C# CS0414 Field is never used even if it is used

Tags: c#, warnings

There is such struct in my code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct ByteBuffer
{
    internal unsafe fixed byte bytes[4];
}
```

Then field of this type:

```
private ByteBuffer bytesBuffer;
```

In class constructor I'm initializing bytesBuffer:

```
this.bytesBuffer = new ByteBuffer();
```

And, using it:

```
fixed (byte* bytes = this.bytesBuffer.bytes)
...
```

But, **Visual Studio 2015 Community** gives me a warning that variable was assigned but never used.
I don't want to supress this warning by pragmas. I just want to fix it.

Comment: how do you know it is for bytesBuffer and not for any other variable....

Comment: Visual Studio has pointed warning at `private ByteBuffer bytesBuffer;`